# How to append div to document, not to body, in javascript in Firefox extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I am new to writing Firefox extension and want to append a `div` to a document, not to the body of webpage, in JavaScript in a Firefox extension. How can I do this?

```
   var div = document.createElement("div");
   div.id = "div1";
   div.textContent = "Its my div";
   var st = div.style;
   st.display = "block";
   st.top = "0px";
   st.left = "0px";
   st.width = "100%";
   document.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: What kind of add-on? (SDK, XUL) Where do you run that code? And could you clarify your question in general? I don't really understand what exactly it is you want to do...

Comment: i am creating div in overlay.js file means in javascript

Answer (score 1):

`document.documentElement` gives you the DOM element of the HTML tag.

```
document.documentElement.appendChild(div);
```

Answer (score 1):

When using XUL-overlays (and XUL windows), please note that `window` and `document` do not refer to the web content, but the XUL window itself (the browser itself).

```
document.documentElement.localName == "window"; // not "html"
document.documentElement.namespaceURI == "http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
```

You need to use [`content` or `gBrowser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Getting_document_of_currently_selected_tab) to interact with the websites loaded in a tab in a browser window (`browser.xul` in Firefox)

For example, to have your code create and add a `<div>` to the `<html>` of a the website in the selected tab (not that it makes sense, but it seems to be what the question is asking for)

```
var div = content.document.createElement("div"); // note the use of `content`
div.id = "div1";
div.textContent = "Its my div";
var st = div.style;
st.display = "block";
st.top = "0px";
st.left = "0px";
st.width = "100%";
content.document.documentElement.appendChild(div); // note the use of `content`
```

Of course, that example will only work when:

1. Executed after the browser window itself was full loaded
2. The currently active tab is actually an html document and loaded enough to have a usable DOM.

See e.g. the ["Detecting page load"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Tabbed_browser#Detecting_page_load) section and other documentation and examples on that page and related/linked pages.

On a somewhat related issue, please note that the Firefox code and all XUL overlays do share a common scope/namespace, and you therefore need to make sure that the global variables your code uses do not conflict or have the potential to conflict with other code. Usually you do this by [prefixing/namespacing your stuff](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/School_tutorial/JavaScript_Object_Management) or using only an anonymous function to get a non-shared function scope.

```
var div = ...; // bad, might conflict with other code
(function() {
  "use strict";
  // strict mode, to make implicit variable declarations an error, among other thiings

  var div = "..."; // OK, local to the anonymous function
  ...
})();
```